# How to put a javascript variable into view in mvc 4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I know that is a small problem, but i didn't found any solution, so i have a javascript variable    `<script>
            var coords = []; </script>` and i want to put it in my **view** :

```
<input type="submit" name="Tracking" value="Tracking" data-coords="//here !!!"/>
```

so please if someone have any idea i will be very appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1;
You Can use this code;

```
 $("[name='Tracking']").attr("data-coords",coords);
```

Method 2;

if dont required use data-coords

you can use jquery .data()..

replace this;

```
<input type="submit" id="Tracking" name="Tracking" value="Tracking"/>
```

and

```
$("#Tracking").data("data-coords", coords);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it on the client side:

```
// javascript version
// safe, if you have only one element that has a name "Tracking"
var btn = document.getElementsByName("Tracking")[0].value;
var a = document.createAttribute('data-coords');
a.value = coords;
btn.setAttributeNode(a);

// or do it easier with jquery
$('[name="Tracking"]').attr('data-coords', coords);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set dynamic values to something in your HTML, you should use JavaScript to do it. The exact way of doing this depends on context - when exactly you want to set those values and what you want to do with them before.

If you want to set value of `data-coords` on DOM load and you use jQuery, write code that updates `data-coords` attribute of this `input` inside [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. You can use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to do this if you use jQuery.